# Cannot find name 'BrowseAnimationModule'

Tags: angular, typescript, import

Does anyone knows how to install or solve this import problem I have the dir animations on @angular/platform-browser/animations bur it dosent imports

```
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { SidebarComponent } from './sidebar/sidebar.component';
import { WorksComponent } from './works/works.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    SidebarComponent,
    WorksComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    CommonModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: can you share your package.json file please?

Answer (score 1):

you should import it

```
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
```

Comment: I did but it dosent work